# Is there any way to add multiple "Auto Number Prefix" in oracle ucm?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-ucm

See, I have a requirement in which I am supposed to change the "Auto Number Prefix" for only one profile, I am wondering if there is any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants the answer for this, I found the method to provide the different prefix for different profile type. Go in Admin Server-> Configuration -> Paste this code;

```
AutoNumberPrefix=<$if dDocType like 'Profile_name'$>Prefix Name<$else$>another prefix name<$endif$>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set [AutoNumberPrefix](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/CSIDO/GUID-725CE6AA-C065-4A98-AFDC-12EB76BC5434.htm#CSIDO-GUID-DE8F1D7A-647F-4398-9C7C-793B142CEA89) in a [rule side effect](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2016/02/rule-side-effects-webcenter-content/) and have it apply only to that rule/profile.

```
<$AutoNumberPrefix="profile1_"$>
```

Comment: Hey Jonathan thankyou for your answer, but this is not working when I am applying it it rule's side effect. Perhaps, I am thinking I should tweak this code a bit and then driectly use it in configuration,This is the code I am thinking, if(#active.dDocAccount       like"Account_Type{<$AutoNumberPrefix="prefix_"$>
}

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code shown as "correct" is actually the more inflexible way to do this.  Any changes require a restart of the Content Server.

Jonathan's answer was really close, but the syntax used ensures that the variable "AutoNumberPrefix" remains in the profile context.  It needs to be placed into local data to be used.  This is accomplished using the function "dpPromote".

```
<$dpPromote("AutoNumberPrefix","profile1_")$>
```